# How to avoid mysqli::query(): Empty query

Tags: php, mysqli

He  guys,

I am fairly new to PHP and wondering how I could keep this "mysqli::query(): Empty query" warning away. The problem is, when I input either a comment OR a rating into my form (and not both), it seems that either 'comment' or the 'rating' query tries to run with an empty string, therefore it returns a warning.

How do I set it so that when a users chooses not to input a comment or a rating it does not throw back the warning ?
I tried doing this with:

```
//Check if comment is entered else set it to an empty string
if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    $commentText = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
} else {
    $commentText = "";
}
```

And then to check if it is an empty string, and if it is, only send the other query.

```
//If user enters either rate or comment (or both) send a query to table.
//Else only send the query with the users input which the user has entered.
if (($rate >= 1) && ($rate <= 5)) {
    if ($commentText === "") {
        $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('".$rate."','".$id."')";
    }
    else {
        $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('".$rate."','".$id."')";
        $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('".$commentText."','".$id."')";
    }   
}
else {
    $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('".$commentText."','".$id."')";
}
```

But it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        include("dbconnect.php");
        error_reporting(E_ALL);



        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

            //Place all data out of the database, with the ID number retrieved out of the url in $result.
            $game = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM beoordeling WHERE id = '" . $id . "'");
        }
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dusk Drive</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php        
            /*  
             * 
             * @ToDo: Make point system show avarage rating
             * 
             * @ToDo: Create a webmaster page where you can add games to the list
             * and automaticly create game page.
             * 
             */




            //CommentList retrieves all comments with id = x.
            $commentList = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE form_id = '" . $id . "'");  



            //While a row of data exists, put that row in $data as an associative array.
            while($data = $game->fetch_assoc()) {
                //Retrieve the file name from the database and place it in the <embed> tags as src="...".
                echo "<embed width='800' height='512' src='" . $data['file'] . "'; type='application/x-shockwave-flash'></embed><br />";
            }  


        //Echo the form with a text box and a rating box.
        echo '<div id="game_form"><form method="POST">
            <a>Leave a comment</a><br />
          <input type="text" name="comments" />
          <br /><a>Rate this game</a><br />  
        <select name="rategame">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />   
        </form></div>';

            //Create a table with all the comments  
            echo "<table>";

            while($cdata = $commentList->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $cdata["comment"] . "</td> <br /><br />";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

        //Submit functionality    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        //Check if comment is entered else set it to an empty string
        if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            $commentText = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
        } else {
            $commentText = "";
        }

        $rate = $_POST['rategame'];

        echo $rate;

        //If user enters either rate or comment (or both) send a query to table.
        //Else only send the query with the users input which the user has entered.
        if (($rate >= 1) && ($rate <= 5)) {
            if ($commentText === "") {
                $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('".$rate."','".$id."')";
                $sqlcomment = ""; //Initializing to null to avoid error.
            }
            else {
                $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('".$rate."','".$id."')";
                $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('".$commentText."','".$id."')";
            }   
        }
        else {
            if ($commentText !== "") {
            $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('".$commentText."','".$id."')";
            $sqlrate = ""; //initializing to null to avoid error.
            }
        }

        //Check if query succeeded or return error
        if (($conn->query($sqlcomment) === TRUE) || ($conn->query($sqlrate) === TRUE)) {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Thank you! Your comment or vote has been received.');</script>";
        } 
        else {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for your vote and comment!);</script>";
        } 


        //Close connection to free up resources.
        $conn->close();
        }
    ?>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Sincerly thanks for your help!

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sqlcomment in USBWebserver v8.6\root\Flash game website\detail.php on line 108

Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in USBWebserver v8.6\root\Flash game website\detail.php on line 108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in else [part also check for `$commentText`

```
if ($commentText === "") {
    $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('".$rate."','".$id."')";
}

if (($rate >= 1) && ($rate <= 5)) {
    if ($commentText === "") {
        $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('".$rate."','".$id."')";
        $sqlcomment = "";//initializing to null to avoid error.
    }
    else {
        $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('".$rate."','".$id."')";
        $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('".$commentText."','".$id."')";
    }   
}
else {
    if ($commentText !== "") {// this is the condition before insert.
         $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('".$commentText."','".$id."')";
         $sqlrate = "";initializing to null to avoid error.
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
if($sqlcomment) {
     $conn->query($sqlcomment) 
}

if($sqlrate) {
     $conn->query($sqlrate) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But when I input only a rating into the form, it still responds with this warning: 

Notice: Undefined variable: sqlcomment in \USBWebserver v8.6\root\Flash game website\detail.php on line 110

Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in \USBWebserver v8.6\root\Flash game website\detail.php on line 110

Comment: Best suggession is to initialize all variables before using it.

Comment: @Dennis1679 u can check my updates answer, just initializing variables to null will solve ur error

Comment: Thanks Niranjan, unfortunatly it still returns error.
Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in \USBWebserver v8.6\root\Flash game website\detail.php on line 112

Comment: add the code where you are running the query?? U have to check before that.

Comment: @Dennis1679 see the answer, i have added at last.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand you right away, but what do you mean by // run query here. ? I need to call the variable $sqlrate there for example ?

Comment: Show me how you are running your query. I will tel you where to change.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you meant, please tell me if I'm wrong. See my first post (which I edited) to see the complete code (where the query is, I think).

Comment: There is none. Except what I have got displayed in the code I put in the first post.

Comment: then in which line you are getting empty error?? Im asking where are you executing the queries??

Comment: if (($conn->query($sqlcomment) === TRUE) || ($conn->query($sqlrate) === TRUE))

Is where I get the error

Comment: Really sorry I didn't get it right away :) Still learning every day.

Comment: It fixed it !  :D Thanks @NiranjanNRaju

Comment: Well, for now yes! But I'm sure to run into some problems in the near future. But anyway thanks again for your help.